# jquery doesn't change my listbox cakephp

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cakephp, listbox

well my problem is that my function doesn't change my listbox, the weird think is that some days before it was working but now it doesn't anymore.

in my view i have this:

```
<script>
function show_alert()
{
   if (confirm("¿Esta seguro de guardar el formulario?")) { return true; } 
   return false;
}
</script>
<?php
echo $this->Html->css(array('buttons'));
echo $this->Html->script('alertify');
echo $this->Html->css(array('alertify.core', 'alertify.default'));
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
 ?>
<div class="actions">
<ul>
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link( "Volver Atrás",   array('action'=>'index') ); ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
<table style="weight: 100%">
    <div id="contenedorr10" style="right:20px; float: right;">
        <h3 align="right"><?php echo $this->Time->format('F jS, Y', time());?></h3>

        <h3 align="right" style="font-size:14px">
            <?php 
                if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){

                echo $this->Html->link( "Cerrar Sesión",   array('action'=>'logout') , array('class' => 'large green awesome')); 
                }else{
                echo $this->Html->link( "Regresar al login de usuarios", array('action'=>'login'), array('class' => 'large green awesome')); 
                }
            ?>          
        </h3>

    </div>
</table>
<div class="cambiodolar form">
<h3 align="center"><strong align="center">AGREGAR ASOCIACIONES</strong></h3>
<table align="left" width="50px">
    <tr>
        <td width="20px">
            <h3 align="right" style="font-size:18px"><strong align="center">FUNCIÓN:</strong></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3 align="left" style="font-size:18px">Panel de Registro</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20px">
            <h3 align="right" style="font-size:18px"><strong align="center">ACCIÓN:</strong></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3 align="left" style="font-size:18px">Registro de Asociaciones</h3>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td width="20px">
            <h3 align="right" style="font-size:18px"><strong align="center">SUJETO:</strong></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3 align="left" style="font-size:18px">Asociaciones</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>     
</table>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SoyaAsociaciones');?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php 

        echo $this->Form->input('nombre', array('label' => 'Ingrese Nombre de la Asociación','style'=>'width:500px; height:30px;'));
        echo $this->Form->input('soya_rubro_id', 
            array('options' => $rubros,
                'id' => 'PostRubroId',
                'empty' => '--Porfavor selecione--',
                'label' => 'Seleccione rubro')
            );
        echo $this->Form->input('soya_subrubro_id', 
            array( 'id' => 'PostSubrubroId',
                'empty' => '--Porfavor selecione--',
                'label' => 'Seleccione subrubro' )
            );
          echo $this->Form->input('ciudad_id', array( 'options' => $ciudades,'empty' => '--Por favor seleccione--','label' => 'Seleccione Ciudad' ));
        echo $this->Form->submit('Agregar Asociación', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Presione aqui para agregar datos', 'onclick' => 'return show_alert();')); 

        $this->Js->get('#PostRubroId')->event('change', 
        $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'soyasubrubros',
        'action'=>'getByRubro'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#PostSubrubroId',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
                ))
            ))
        );

?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<h3>Acciones</h3>
</div>
```

and in my controller i have this:

```
public function getByRubro() {
        $this->loadModel('SoyaSubrubro');

        $soya_rubro_id = $this->request->data['SoyaAsociaciones']['soya_rubro_id'];
        debug($soya_rubro_id);
        $subcategories = $this->SoyaSubrubro->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array('SoyaSubrubro.soya_rubro_id' => $soya_rubro_id),
            'fields'=>'subrubro',
            'recursive' => -1
            ));
        debug($this->set('subcategories',$subcategories));
        $this->set('subcategories',$subcategories);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
```

and in my getByRubro view i have this:

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($subcategories)){
        foreach ($subcategories as $key => $value): 
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php 
        endforeach; 
    } else { 
?>
    <option value="">No Data</option>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

well when i change the "soya_rubro_id" listbox and i change the option i t doesn't load my model of "SubRubros" i don't know why, please help, thanks in advance...

Comment: try putting this line in view/layouts/default.ctp               echo $this->Html->script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');